# How do I specify a Wildfly server version when using wildfly-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, wildfly

When I start my webapp using the `wildfly-maven-plugin` (`mvn wildfly:run`), it starts with Wildfly 10. I need to test it with Wilfly 8.1.

Is there some parameter for chosing the Wildfly server version?

This is the piece of `pom.xml` I used to enable `wildfly:run`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Did you RTFM at [WildFly Maven Plugin](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/index.html)?

Comment: Yes, @SteveC. There is a version parameter, but I still got a Wildfly 10 running when I set it to 8.1. I'm assuming I used it wrongly, but I googled around and couldn't find an example.

Comment: Use the [jbossHome](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/run-mojo.html#jbossHome) parameter

Comment: @SteveC, isn't that for specifying where my Wildfly is installed? I don't have a Wildfly installation. When I execute `mvn wildfly:run` Maven downloads and starts a version of Wildfly for me, if it isn't already installed. Only it is version 10 and I want version 8.1. Is this possible?

Comment: Show your pom.xml?

Comment: Is this enough, @uthark.

Comment: Just tried passing parameter -Dwildfly.version=8.1 in the command line, works as expected. https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/run-mojo.html

Comment: @uthark, that did work for me, but with "8.1.0.Final" as the value. I added `<configuration><version>8.1.0.Final</version></configuration>` to my pom.xml, but that doesn't work.

Comment: @lpacheco see documentation: user property is `wildfly.version`, not `version`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131360/discussion-between-lpacheco-and-uthark).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options:

1. Configure user property in `pom.xml`:

   ```
   <properties>
       <wildfly.version>8.1.0.Final</wildfly.version>
   </properties>
   <build>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
   </build>
   ```
2. Set required version in plugin configuration section:

   ```
   <plugins> 
       <plugin> 
           <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId> 
           <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
           <version>1.0.2.Final</version> 
           <configuration> 
               <version>8.1.0.Final</version> 
           </configuration> 
       </plugin> 
   </plugins>
   ```
3. Pass required version using command-line argument:

   ```
   mvn wildfly:run -Dwildfly.version=8.1.0.Final
   ```

See [plugin documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/run-mojo.html) for details.

Comment: I'm using Maven modules and my webapp is a module. Configuring the plugin in the module's POM didn't work, only passing the parameter from the CLI did. Moving the configuration to the `<PluginManagement>` of the parent POM made it work. I'm not sure why it is like this.

Comment: Only option that is working for me is to use the command-line argument